# Android SQLite query split?

Tags: android, sqlite, split

I'm coding an app with a database and I have a question:

I have query: f.e.: SELECT one, two FROM table WHERE name = "test"

My output ist in the TextView: one, two

Is it possible to "split" this query into two queries to get 2 variables with one query? 
Like: 
SELECT one FROM table WHERE name = "test"
SELECT two FROM table WHERE name = "test"

I don't want to use two queries.

I'm using an arraylist to save the results from the queries.

Comment: what's wrong with the the first query?

Comment: nothing. I want the two columns which are selected in 2 variables.

Comment: the first query does not work? you don't get column one and two from table name "table" for the particular row "test"?.

Comment: the entries of the two columns are saved in one variable: String text ="entryone, entrytwo". this is what i get. but i don't want one variable, i want to have 2: String text1 = "entryone" String text2 = "entrytwo".

Answer (score 0):

The first query is fine, your second example is just making 2 queries do the job of the first one.  I think your really asking is how to get the respective columns into respective array lists, if so see [One column to array SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848420/one-column-to-array-sqlite/17914272#17914272)

Hope this helps.